# How can i count the first and the last index of max sequence?

Tags: python, loops

```
monets = []
for i in range(20):
    choices = ['Tails', 'Eagle']
    monets.append(random.choice(choices))
cnt = 0
prev = 0
for i, e in enumerate(monets):
    if e == 'Eagle':
        cnt += 1
        if e == 'Eagle' and i == len(monets) - 1 and cnt > prev:
                prev = cnt
    elif e != 'Eagle':
        if prev < cnt:
            prev = cnt
        cnt = 0

print(monets)
print(prev)
```

My code calculates the max sequence of 'Eagle' in random generated list, but i stuck on how to calculate first and last index of this sequence. I figured out that using enumerate may help me with it, but i mixed up.  Example: ['Tails', 'Eagle','Eagle','Tails','Eagle'] => output: 1,2

Comment: do you mean maximal _consecutive_ sequence of terms?

Answer (score 2):

This should works, this is a simple algorithm, you don't need any sophisticated libraries:

*(revision 2)*

```
m = 0
c = 0
p = -1

for [i,s] in enumerate(monets):
    if s == 'Eagle':
        c += 1
    else:
        c = 0
    if c > m: 
        m = c
        p = i

print('max Eagle:', m, 'from:', p + 1 - m, 'to:', p)
```

Comment: Nice one but it is required the starting and end position of the maximal sequence not the maximal length

Comment: yeah, I'm little bit to rush

Comment: you could omit the brackets in  `[i, s]`, just `i, s` or use tuple `(i, s)` which are more "performant" than list

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `itertools.groupby` to get groups of consecutive "Eagles". Combine that with `enumerate`, as in your approach, to pair them with the indices, and use `max` to find the longest sequence. Finally, get the indices from the first and last elements of that list.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby                                                                           
>>> monets = ['Tails', 'Eagle','Eagle','Tails','Eagle']                                                     
>>> max((list(g) for k, g in groupby(enumerate(monets), key=lambda x: x[1]) if k == "Eagle"), key=len)      
[(1, 'Eagle'), (2, 'Eagle')]
>>> _[0][0], _[-1][0]                                                                                       
(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reading your code, looks like you've got following computation working (i.e. generally correct, but I didn't actually run and test for bugs)

```
['Tails', 'Eagle','Eagle','Tails','Eagle']  # monets list
[      0,       1,      2,      0,      1]  # 'Eagle' sequence lengths
```

There are a few different ways to do what you want, but continuing on your existing methodology, you can indeed use `enumerate` to generate the following:

```
[ (0, 0),  (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0), (4, 1)]  # seq lengths from before, enumerated
```

Where each pair represents: `(index, length)`

From that, find the pair with the largest length, and you'll have the end index of the sequence, in this case: `(2, 2)`.

The first instance of `length == 1`, searching backwards from the end index, will give you the start index.

**Sidenote**: @tobias_k's answer is written in a more functional style (which I also personally prefer). It's a different methodology than you've started with, but I highly recommend learning it. Here is that method written more (IMO) readably:

```py
import itertools as it

monets = ['Tails', 'Eagle','Eagle','Tails','Eagle']
grouped = it.groupby(enumerate(monets), key=lambda pair: pair[1])
eagle_seqs = [list(seq) for v, seq in grouped if v == 'Eagle']
longest_seq = max(eagle_seqs, key=len)
seq_idxs = [i for i, _ in longest_seq]

start_idx, end_idx = seq_idxs[0], seq_idxs[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most elegant solution to this problem:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

monets = []
for i in range(20):
    choices = ['Tails', 'Eagle']
    monets.append(random.choice(choices))
```

Here the only additional thing to do is to encode the seq into num values and find the longest contiguous sequence of indices:

```
encode_ = {'Tails': 0, 'Eagle': 1}
df = pd.DataFrame(monets).replace(encode_)
A = np.where(df == 1)[0]
result = max(np.split(A, np.where(np.diff(A) != 1)[0] + 1), key=len).tolist()
start_idx, end_idx = result[0],result[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a down-to-ground approach: (it returns the position of the 1st maximal sequence of consecutive terms)

```
lst = ['Tails', 'Eagle', 'Eagle','Tails', 'Eagle', 'Eagle','Eagle', 'Eagle', 'Tails', 'Eagle', 'Eagle','Tails']

index, counter = -1, 0
tmp_i, tmp_c = -1, 0
for i, v in enumerate(lst):
    if v == 'Eagle':
        # tmp-update
        tmp_c += 1
        if tmp_i == -1:
            tmp_i = i
    else:
        if tmp_c > counter:
            # global update
            counter = tmp_c
            index = tmp_i
        # reset
        tmp_i, tmp_c = -1, 0

# final check for occurrence of max sequence at the end of the list 
if tmp_c > counter:
    # global update
    counter = tmp_c
    index = tmp_i

boundaries_max_seq = (index, index + counter - 1)

print(boundaries_max_seq)
# (4, 7)
```

Comment: this will fail with: `lst = ['Eagle', 'Tails', 'Tails', 'Eagle', 'Eagle', 'Eagle'] # output (0, 0)`

Comment: @Jupri  thanks, it makes sense. When the max sequence is found at the end of the list one needs to apply a further check (outside the loop, "at indentation level 0"). I will fix it

Comment: yes, beware the last item